# Is there an English translation of Graetz's "Kohelet"?

Tags: ecclesiastes, hermeneutical-approaches

Heinrich Graetz wrote a commentary to Ecclesiastes in German in 1871 (viewable [here](https://babel.hathitrust.org/shcgi/pt?id=uc1.%24b110109;view=1up;seq=1)) which is quoted relatively widely among modern scholars. I would like to read it (especially the Introduction) in English if there is an available translation. Is there such a translation and is it available for viewing or purchase online?

Answer (score 3):

Your link is behind a login. Here's [an alternative source](https://archive.org/details/kohletoderders00grae). **The short answer to your question is "No".**<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> If I am wrong, the person on the planet who will know is [Stuart Weeks](https://www.dur.ac.uk/theology.religion/staff/profile/?id=675). See his very recent paper on [the interpretation of Qohelet](https://www.academia.edu/5667535/Googling_Qohelet) (unpublished). His contact details are on his staff page, and if you sent him a short, polite request on Graetz, he might have something to offer.</sub>

Comment: Thanks David. I sent Stuart Weeks an email, so I'll see if he knows of anything.

Comment: I've just prepared the introduction from the german scan into formatted text. It's still german (not yet translated as you looked for) and all greek and/or hebrew pieces of text are lost. If this might be helpful for you (possibly google translate of the core pieces?) email me with reference to this comment/answer.